# windowDidLoad not called (again)

Tags: swift, nswindowcontroller

This is driving me nuts. I have a couple of windows in my app which I open via a menu. I now added a new window, but it's `windowDidLoad` is never called.

```
fileprivate let paymentWindowController = PaymentWindowController(windowNibName:"PaymentWindow")
```

is the declaration in my `AppDelegate` where I issue a

```
paymentWindowController.loadWindow()
```

in its `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

When my menu is clicked it invokes

```
@IBAction func showPayments(_ sender: Any) {
  paymentWindowController.window!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
}
```

The `PaymentWindowController` is just the scaffold which is created via New File/Cocoa/NSWindowController:

```
class PaymentWindowController: NSWindowController {
  override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    print("never been here")
  }
}
```

The XIB has only the single window also from the scaffold. (I just renamed the XIB from `PaymentWindowController.xib` to `PaymentWindow.xib` like I did that for the other windows too.)

All other windows were created the same way and work as expected. But this bastard won't work as it should.

I also have cleaned the project and even erased Derived Data.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your xib, cleaning the project, and then rebuilding the xib? I occasionally run into issues like this with custom xibs, and sometimes rebuilding it is the only thing that works. Probably not the answer your were hoping for, but it's worth a shot! There are other questions similar yours on SO that i'm sure you can pull from as well. I could pull answers from those, but it would be redundant at that point. You've probably seen it all. Good luck!

Comment: @user3353890 It's really hair-pulling... See my own answer.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I need to add

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  // initialize
}
```

to my code which actually gets called. No idea why I got fooled by `windowDidLoad` which is created by the scaffold but never gets called.

Comment: It seems to only be an issue on 10.14 and below, windowDidLoad correctly gets called on macOS Big Sur at least